# Why is the alert box returning "undefined undefined"?

Tags: javascript, return

I am trying to alert the values in each conditional of a loop below (in the function returnFunction). I have a function myFunction that is structured as so:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    window.myArray = {
        1: returnFunction("a"),
        2: returnFunction("b"),
        3: returnFunction("c"),
        4: returnFunction("d"),
        5: returnFunction("e"),
        6: returnFunction("f"),
        7: returnFunction("g")
    }
}
```

returnFunction looks like this:

```
var returnFunction = function (classID) {
    var myArray = [], tempcounter = 0;

    tempcounter = document.getElementsByClassName(classID).length;

    myArray = {classID : tempcounter};

    return alert(myArray[0] + ' ' + myArray[1]); 

}
```

The returned value that is alerted is **undefined undefined**

It's my understanding the flow here is that when myFunction is called, it calls returnFunction 7 times, each time sending a different string ("a" through "g") that represent a specific class in the DOM. For a given class "a" through "g", the number of instances of the class (classID) is then counted and returns the classID and a number, which should be returned in the alert.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: `myArray = {classID : tempcounter}` ... that turns it into an object. not saying this helps, but you shouldn't be confusing arrays with objects. you do it with `window.myArray` too.

Comment: I know...this was the code block I was given (on my job) to work with and I'm not allowed to change it

Comment: well you are taking in a classID (say, `'d'`), then assigning it as an object to `myArray`, then trying to access the first item in that array ... but there is no array. if you tried to alert `myArray['d']` that would work, but `myArray[0]` wouldn't because you didn't pass in a `classID` of `'0'`.

Comment: But if I rewrite the myArray in returnFunction as myArray[classID : tempcounter] it throws an error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  "

Comment: i think what you are looking for isn't `myArray = {classID : tempcounter}`, but something like `myArray.push(classID).push(tempcounter)`. This will push the value `d` as `myArray[0]` and the length returned as `myArray[1]`.

Comment: oh, and in the future, learn the difference between objects and arrays before you try to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is something of a mess, so I'll try to clean it up.

Assuming the point of this function is to capture the current length for all objects on the page, this is a bit clearer:

```
var classArr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
    lengthObj = {},
    getLength = function(classID){
        return document.getElementsByClassname(classID).length;
    },
    lengthFunc = function(){
        for(var i = classArr.length; i--;){
            lengthObj[i+1] = {
                classArr[i]:getLength(classArr[i])
            };
        }
    }

lengthFunc();
```

This does the following:

- Builds an array of the classIDs you have
- Creates window-level empty object
- Creates method to return the number of items for a specific classID
- Creates method that assigns each length retrieved from getLength method to its appropriate classID

By the way, it made no sense whatsoever to return an `alert` to a value of an object (or array, either one), but it made way more sense to assign the object of `classID:length` to each value. Last note is that I would make the `lengthFunc` 0-indexed instead of 1-indexed, but I kept it the same as you had it, hence the `[i+1]`.

Comment: I understand it's a mess....deadline tomorrow and I'm in a rush. Thanks...getting rid of the colon and pushing in the value for tempcounter worked

Answer (score 0):

In the returnFunction, change

```
myArray = { classID : tempcounter};
return alert(myArray[0] + ' ' + myArray[1]);
```

to

```
myArray[classID]  = tempcounter;
return alert(classID + ' ' + myArray[classID]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
myArray = { classID: tempCounter}
```

In particular you created an object, not an array, with one key, the key being `classID`. This object does not have the key `0` nor the key `1`. Therefore `myArray['classID']` will be defined, but `myArray[0]` will not be. Note the object

```
foo = { '0': tempCounter }
```

will be defined for `foo[0]`. This is what it would like to create an object with keys as numbers, in contrast to creating an array.

You should use an array instead of an object, or access the object as objects are accessed, not as arrays are accessed.